# Nigei Batim / Tzara'as of houses with a house and another level (aliya)

Tags: home-house, tzaraas-negaim

If one person owns the bottom floor of a house and another owns the floor on top, what happens when the one on the lower floor has tzara'as in their house and the house needs destroying? Assuming the upper floor can't stand without the lower floor, does the person on top just lose their home?

Answer (score 4):

This halacha is brought in the Mishnah Negaim 13:3 in which it says that the upper floor is reinforced and kept standing:

> בַּיִת שֶׁנִּרְאָה בוֹ נֶגַע, הָיְתָה עֲלִיָּה עַל גַּבָּיו, נוֹתֵן אֶת הַקּוֹרוֹת לָעֲלִיָּה. נִרְאָה בָעֲלִיָּה, נוֹתֵן אֶת הַקּוֹרוֹת לַבָּיִת

> A house in which a nega appeared if it had an upper chamber above it, the beams are considered part of the upper chamber. If the nega appeared in the upper chamber the beams are considered part of the lower room.

The Bartenura explains that this means that we reinforce the upper floor and leave it standing;

> נותן את הקורות לעלייה. וסומכן בעמודין ואינו נותצן עם הבית, דכתיב את אבניו ואת עציו ואת [כל] עפר הבית, ולא אבנים ועצים ועפר של עלייה

The Yachin on that Mishnah 13:27 states  clearly that there’s no difference if the upper floor is owned by the same person or someone else, in both cases we leave it standing;

> סתמא דמתניתין משמע בין ששניהן שייכין לאדם א' או לב' בנ"א כך הוא הדין

He then has a long debate how to differentiate between this and the case of shared walls.